# Can't add project as library to my project

Tags: android

I'm trying to use ABS library in my project. I added library project to my workspace, checked this state ("Is Library" is true in project's settins), added this project to my one "Java Build Path" -> "Projects". But I can't mark this project as library ("Android"->"Libraries" in properties). I had added that, but when I opened it again, I saw that project hadn't been added. How can I fix it?

Comment: Be sure that you add libraries into "libs" folder, that's how ADT likes it

Answer (score 0):

Undo this step:

> added this project to my one "Java Build Path" -> "Projects".

You only need to add a library project project under the Android -> Libraries in properties

Comment: The steps should be like this.. 1.) Import ABS 2.) Mark ABS as a library project by checking "Is library" .. 3.) Make sure ABS compiles.. 4.) in your other project. Android -> Library.. Click "Add". Pick ABS from the list. If that doesn't work its possible you have another issue with your project

Answer (score -1):

Check your files to see if they are read-only, especially build.properties.

If you use source control, they will tend to be set to read-only and Eclipse doesn't seem to provide any warnings when it needs to write to these files and can't -- you'll check the box, it looks good, then you exit and reload and it's unchecked!